# Possible machine learning methodology to implement both continuous features and features with descrete values in the same model

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, predictive-models

I would like to implement a machine learning procedure, in order to predict a categorical binary outcome. However, my main concern, is the different "nature" of my features: while a proportion of my features have discrete binary values, such as "yes" or "no", the others are essentially continuous numeric variables. Thus, as im mainly working in R, is there a package or methodology that can handle both "types" of features into training a classifier ? or i have to separare my data set into two datasets, each comprised of the different type of features ?

Comment: Logistic regression, SVM, random forest, neural networks, Naive Bayes, Cubist, gmb, xgboost and many more are all capable of doing this.

Comment: Dear user777 thank you for your answer !! Actually, i didn't knew that gmb (perhaps you meant gbm?) or random forests could handle not only continuous variables of different "nature", but also different "types" of features. In your opinion, also a transformation on the data would be also essential ? especially for the continuous ones ?

Answer (score 2):

You can have both continuous and binary values when making a classifier. You're model will have what is known as [dummy variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)) in it. As a first pass, I would give a go at [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression), but there are many, many different types of ways to do this.

Let's say you had a problem wanting to predict if someone will vote (so your binary outcomes) and you have two features: gender and income. In r you would try something like:

`logistic_model = glm(Vote ~ Income + Gender, family=binomial, data=mydataset)`

Comment: Dear dmb, thank you for your answer and example !! Actually, i also might try different types of models, like the logistic regression you meant above, or ensemble models. One crusial question: due to the different nature of variables, does a tranformation be essential ? or due to the "dummy " variables you mentioned, it would not be appropriate?